# self.image.frame.width = 20 give get only property error

Tags: swift, imageview

i tried to change the width of my Image view to 20 
`@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!` using this code in viewDidLoad `self.image.frame.width = 20`
but it give me error cannot assign to property: `width` is a get only property. what does that mean?? sorry i am new to swift i do not know what it mean.please help

Comment: `self.image.frame.**size**.width = 20`

Answer (score 26):

get-only means you can only read this property (for example to compare with something), but not change. To set width you need this:

```
self.image.frame.size.width = foo
```

Answer (score 2):

There is 2 ways to solve this:

1. self.image.frame.size.width = some value
2. You can add width constraint to your view (by code, storyboard or xib) and set this constraint's constant property to some value

Answer (score 1):

Swift:

```
let widthValue = self.view.frame.size.width
self.btnName.frame.size.width = widthValue
self.txtEMail.frame.size.width = (widthValue - 32)
self.lblUserName.frame.size.width = (widthValue * 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> self.image.frame.size.width = 200

self.UIView.frame.width is read only property